# Progress cursor with a cross instead of the arrow

Tags: html, css, user-experience

Some parts of my web-application are using the standard `crosshair` [cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor). When a request to the server is pending, I would like to notify the user by displaying the `progress` cursor.

However, the use of `crosshair` is really important. Is there a way to display a cursor which would look like the `progress` one, but with a cross (like in `crosshair`) instead of the arrow?

I know I can use my own cursors in order to do that, but that would be disastrous for the [user experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17933/are-custom-cursors-a-good-idea-in-most-desktop-applications). In summary:

- Can I use together two cursors?
- If not, can I use a system cursor as an image, in order to create my own-compound cursor?
- If not, what solution would you propose?

Comment: You could always create your own and do `cursor: url(custom.cur);`

Comment: Yep, that's what I have written :) . But I can't make a custom cursor which look like the system cursors in all the OS, and see an unknown cursor is really bad for the UX. Hence my question.

Comment: You can use javascript in order to change whenever you need to progress cursor form crosshair. And change back when action complete. Usually I change whatever cursor type to progress before starting Ajax query to the server.

Comment: I know that. My question here is purely about the cursor representation.

Comment: @Blackhole fair point... You *could* (if you really have to) put a JS workaround in that follows the cursor around?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that, that's the point of my question #2: is there a way to use the image of a system cursor (in that case, the `wait` one)?

Comment: well the system cursor changes depending on what system the user has... Short of sniffing for that and conditionally displaying one of a wild variety of custom cursors depending on this I can only really think of the JS method (basic demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ApPSK/1/)

Answer (score 1):

From the UX point of view - I would advice against using the "wait" cursor; If your app is asynchronous and you're using ajax for your requests - you should display a "loader" swirl in the relevant component (table/list/etc.) and leave the cursor as it should be.

Cursor is like an extension of user's hand :-)
If a part of the app is doing something in the background - I would let the user interact with the rest of the app normally.

Comment: Actually, none of the actions that the user can perform locks the interface, not even the component itself. He can always still interact with the component in another way (say, for instance, that after a click, he can still drag the component, or click elsewhere). Well, I know, it sounds like an all-mighty widget - and it is :P . But it's also the core of my app, I really can't change that.

Comment: @Blackhole That's great! And you shouldn't change that. If that's the case - why show progress at all? User doesn't care what you're doing in the background - that cursor would only confuse them: "oh, what is this? Can I still use the app or should I wait?"

Comment: Because after a click, the response of the server to the request which was sent will modify the content of the component. Between the request and the response, nothing happen, and the user has no way to know that his action has really been taken into account by the app. That's why I want to use something like `progress` (with the arrow, or in my case a cross, still visible) and not like `wait`. The message is: "*OK dude, I've understood what you want, I'm processing. But meanwhile, you can continue your business, for sure!*".